# Flutter : Can't run flutter on real device

Tags: flutter

I have this issue when I'm trying to run on my real device
This issue comes when I run without cable
Does it need to upgrade the SDK to the new version?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOpAX.png

Comment: you cannot run on a real device without a cable. A wireless real device is not a real thing yet. or if your question is something else then change the question for that we can understand easily.

Comment: Have you turned on USB Debugging on a real device?